# MongoDB with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, database, mongodb

ALL questions I saw here is too old for understanding so I'm asking a new one.
Im building a social media app that stores data, and will ,at the end, send notification even when the app is offline.
Is MongoDB is a good choice to use with Android Studio to my project ?
I understood that I need first to connect it to Realm and by Realm I use MongoDB.
Do you think its a good DB to use with Android? if it is, do you have any good guides for it?
If not, is there any other DB to use that is easy to learn\use?

PS
I dont want to use Firebase, because of its pricing.
Thank you .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**MongoDB is also available for android** 
The only problem is that it does not have well-structured documentation for android..

I recently managed to connect my android application to the remote database

here is a sample unit application
https://github.com/i-sachinkumar/MongoDB-for-Android

*Its readme file contains all the steps to be followed in the back-end as well as in the android studio*

**Enjoy**